# Did Trinity think she would survive jumping out of a window?

Tags: the-matrix

In Reloaded, Trinity jumps out of the a window while fighting [Agent Thompson](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Thompson). Did she hope that she could survive the fall if no bullet hits her? Or what's her point?

In the Final Fight of the Osiris, [Jue](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Jue) made a similar jump and survived the landing, but I'm not sure it's the same height... Trinity supposed to be in the 66th floor.

Did Trinity think at all?

On the other hand, why didn't she shoot the window from the inside and jump to the next building, just like she and Morpheus did in The Matrix?

Comment: No, she dreamed that her superman would save her.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I think you mean Superneo; http://media.aintitcool.com/coolproduction/ckeditor_assets/pictures/9855/original/flight.JPG?1351304681

Comment: Conversely, did the *agent* that followed her out the window think she would survive?  Because what was the point of all that shooting and to finally hit her if she is just going to splat on the pavement?  Did he know Neo was on his way to rescue her?  Did she suspect he knew something she didn't?

Comment: You know, given that this is the Matrix, believing she could survive the fall may have actually helped to make it *really survivable*.  To say nothing of getting shot at *during* the fall...

Answer (score 18):

Jumping out of the window gave her a better chance than fighting two agents in an enclosed space, where they could overpower her and use teamwork to overcome her agility.

By jumping out of the window she gave herself a chance to survive - perhaps she could have broken the fall (unlikely, but possible, especially if she had managed to find a protrusion from the building like a flagpole).  If the agents followed her out the window, she could have shot them - freefall means they can't exert force against anything to dodge.  She could have been counting on Neo to save her, as well (though she would have no reason to believe he would be able to, other than hope).

Lastly, she may very well have preferred suicide if it came to that.  Recall in the first Matrix: they were going to be forced to kill Morpheus before he could spill their secrets.  She would have been put through the same - torture, mental breakage, and, finally, having her friends (and her love) be forced to kill her.

In her place?  I would certainly choose 'small chance of life, small chance of taking them with me, near certainty of death' over 'no chance to win, likely forcing the love of my life to kill me'.

Comment: Pretty much sums up, how I have always percieved this scene..

Comment: In the intro scene (the "jumping out the window shooting scene" is played out a few times throughout Reloaded), she does actually manage to shoot the agent a few times (you can see some bullets go in and blood) just before he shoot "the bullet" that hits her. So her plan wasn't without some merit. Strangely, in later versions of this scene (i.e. when it "actually happens" and Neo catches her), when he shots the "one bullet", Trinity doesn't appear to land any shots on him. Not sure why that inconsistency is there, but the first version of it shows her actually landing bullets in the agent...

Answer (score 13):

#### Context

Trinity first tries to fight the first Agent (not *that* unsuccessfully, actually, but not clearly winning either) in hand-to-hand combat. He throws Her into the office adjacent to the window where She finally jumps out. When She gets out Her uzis to fire at the first Agent, a second comes in.

#### Situation

Now, She would have to take it up with *two armed* Agents (Thompson and Jackson), in a small room. No possible chance to win, and more importantly, all exits are blocked by Agents, so no possible way to escape into the building, either. They are closing in and there is no other option, than to jump out the window. Especially given that She doesn't have a lot of time to ponder over the matter.

#### What could have gone through Her head

There are a couple possibilities regarding Her plan. You could theorise that She planned to get hold of something (e.g. a flagpole) during falling or maybe even hoped to actually reach the building on the other side of the street. I wouldn't be content with assuming She figured Neo would somehow manage to save Her since it wouldn't fit Her character well, but it *is* a theory.

Last but not least it could have been an action to simply avoid being killed by the hand an Agent, regardless of the implications (dying by falling onto the street).

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out in other answers, Trinity's situation against the Agents in the close quarters of the building was hopeless, whereas she at least had a slim possibility of surviving by jumping out the window. She was firing at the Agents on her way down in an attempt to [suppress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppressive_fire) and/or hit them, after which she could attempt to right herself and land on her feet as Jue did. Unfortunately, Agent Thompson hit **her** instead, and with a bullet wound there was no longer any way for her to try to land on her feet and survive.

It's also worth pointing out that with two Agents fighting her she didn't have as much time to analyze the situation as we do, and she probably simply panicked. Jumping out the window was the only way to put at least some distance between her and the Agents, so it's a reasonable choice for a split-second decision. Zion operatives like Trinity can perform amazing feats in the Matrix, but they are still **only human**.

As for your comparison with Jue from *Final Flight of the Osiris*, there are significant differences between the two jumps. Perhaps the biggest is that Trinity was distracted as she was trying to escape Agents while Jue could focus entirely on the jump and landing. Also, Jue appears to have jumped from a lower height:

[image]

vs

[image]

Finally, as to your last question:

> On the other hand, why didn't she shoot the window from the inside and jump to the next building, just like she and Morpheus did in The Matrix?

In *The Matrix* Trinity jumps from one building to another while running from Agent Brown, but she was at a full sprint whereas in this case she didn't have much of a running start. Also, in *The Matrix* she jumped across a two lane street:

[image]

whereas the image above shows that she would have had to jump across a **six** lane street in *The Matrix Reloaded*.

Morpheus jumps over what appears to be a very wide street while training Neo, but Morpheus was not in any danger at the time and could fully concentrate. Moreover, Morpheus may simply be better at long jumps than Trinity.

Overall, Trinity's choice probably gave her the best chance of survival -- albeit still a very poor one. It's just unfortunate that she was shot and lost all hope of surviving on her own.

Comment: This. That was not a suicide attempt (she's of better moral fiber than to fire on innocent-poople-who-are-agents-atm for no reason - she hits him a few times IIRC). Whatever her plan was went out the window, when she got shot.

Answer (score 4):

Trinity chooses the window because it's her last resort for getting away from the Agents. The script lays it out quite bluntly

> **273** INT. REROUTING FACILITY - CORRIDORS - NIGHT
>   Trinity is getting the shit kicked out of her.
>
> **279** INT. REROUTING FACILITY - CORRIDORS - NIGHT
>   **With no choice left, Trinity dives through the window.**
>
> **281** EXT. FRONT OF REROUTING FACILITY - NIGHT
>   Trinity falls, fighting to the last until she feels the bullet enter her midsection.

---

**So what possible options could Trinity enjoy, having thrown herself out of a window?**

### Landing

In Final Flight of the Osiris, we see a redpill ([Jue](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Jue)) dropping some 200 feet to the ground. She displaces the entire impact into the ground and walks away ***totally unharmed.***

[image]

### Catching something on the way down.

In the Matrix webcomic "[Run, Saga, Run](http://web.archive.org/web/20040603211459/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/kpage00_755.html)", an almost identical situation to Trinity's occurs. Saga is trapped in a climbing elevator and leaps out blindly, in the hopes that her chances will improve once she's away from the Agents. As luck would have it, she was able to catch the cable trailing from a window-cleaner's gantry and swing herself into the side of the building.

[image]

She then drops the last 50-100 feet onto the ground, again with no injury.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The whole purpose for Trinity entering the matrix at this point is because the power grid hasn't been disabled and Neo is due to exit the source in a matter of minutes. Since **#1**: Trinity knows Neo is in the matrix and essentially omniscient due to being able to see the code of the matrix while inside it, would be aware of her presence and her need for his assistance, and **#2**: she was out of options. All exits within the room are covered by two armed agents.

I assume her immediate thought process was that essentially, she had a better chance jumping out of a window than taking on two agents

Comment: I don't think she expected him to catch her.

Comment: interesting idea of her supposedly being aware of Neo's ability to sense her. Albeit whenever they go 'inside the portal', the contact is lost, so she cannot probably be sure, except she knows something I do not. This way if she'd expected him to catch her that would be her irrational side then (a nice thing). It's still unclear why didn't she tried to opt for the opposite building. It seems like she could have tried, perhaps she would be a too clear target for the agents as she couldn't fire back?